# Passing arguments to a function with named arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

How to pass named arguments to a function from another function?

I have looked at wrappers, argparse, Google for the past 8 hours. I am missing something big time.

```
def my_func(a='something', b='something_else'):
    # add a and b
    return something

def slave(func, args):
    result = func(args)
    return result

slave_work = {my_func, (a=50, b=90)}

print (slave(slave_work)
```

Should output `140`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing now is simply passing a set to `slave` as a single argument. So you're probably getting a `TypeError` on a positional argument missing.

You might want to change your `slave_work` to be a dict (right now it is a set), and then it would look like:

```py
slave_work = {'func': my_func, 'args': {'a': 50, 'b': 90}}
```

And now you can unpack the dict by doing:

```py
print(slave(**slave_work))
```

This is more or less equivalent for doing:

```py
print(slave(func=slave_work['func'], args=slave_work['args'])
```

Then inside your `slave` function change accordingly to:

```py
result = func(**args)
```

---

Another option is to use list (or tuple in this case) unpacking. So your `slave_work` can also be:

```py
slave_work = {'func': my_func, 'args': (50, 90)}
```

And then your call to `slave` will be the same, but **inside** `slave` change to:

```py
result = func(*args)
```

The difference is that this will unpack the arguments according to their **position** and not their name.

Answer (score 5):

Python allows to [un/pack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) iterables to positional parameters and mappings to keyword parameters. The syntax is [`*arguments` and `**keywords`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter), respectively.

```
>>> def my_func(a, b):
...     return a - b
...
>>> args = [2, 1]   # iterable for positional arguments
>>> my_func(*args)  # unpack iterable
1
>>> kwargs = {'b': 1, 'a': 2}  # mapping for keyword arguments
>>> my_func(**kwargs)          # unpack mapping
1
```

You can even combine both forms of variadic arguments - e.g. `my_func(*args, **kwargs)`.

---

To create a wrapper function that calls another, you can use this to either:

- Explicitly pass in iterables/mappings:

  ```
  # take regular arguments...
  def slave(func, args, kwargs):
      # ...and unpack them
      result = func(*args, **kwargs)
      return result

  # explicit iterable [1] and mapping {'b': 2}
  print(slave(my_func, [1], {'b': 2}))
  # from existing args/kwargs
  args, kwargs = [1], {'b': 2}
  print(slave(my_func, args, kwargs))
  ```

  Explicit iterables/mappings are simpler for scripted interfaces, i.e. when you have `args`/`kwargs` for use in `slave(func, args, kwargs)`. They are rather cumbersome for manual use, i.e. when you call `slave(func, [1], {'b': 2})`.
- Convert passed in parameters:

  ```
  # take variadic arguments...
  def slave(func, *args, **kwargs):
      # ...and pass them on
      result = func(*args, **kwargs)
      return result

  # explicit iterable [1] and mapping {'b': 2}
  print(slave(my_func, 1, b=2))
  # from existing args/kwargs
  args, kwargs = [1], {'b': 2}
  print(slave(my_func, *args, **kwargs))
  ```

  Implicit iterables/mappings are simpler for manual use, i.e. when you call `slave(func, 1, b=2)`. They are costly for scripted interfaces, i.e. when you have `args`/`kwargs` and must relatedly unpack them in `slave(func, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: I gave the win to the other answer because it worked and I could easily understand it.
Having said that, upon re-reading your answer you give 2 ways of doing things. That's awesome too :)